# "in order" coditional sentence?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

> In order your product is original one I will purchase it.

Does this sound natural? I couldn't find any same structure but still, I am in doubt that it might be correct

Comment: We don't do proofreading here, but I'll tell you that you can just use *if* instead of *in order*.

Comment: The honest truth is that it's not comprehensible at all. You need to tell us what it really is that you want to say with your sentence.

Comment: You might be confusing *in order* with [*in order to*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/in_order_to) or [*in order that*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/in_order_that) or [*in order for*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/in_order_for_(or_that)). Click through these links and then click on "More example sentences" to see how they're used in context.

Comment: Or maybe you're thinking of **in case**.  *If* is really the best thing to say here, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "in case" is what you're looking for. But "if" is perfect as well, as the others have pointed out.

In case your product is an original (one), I will purchase it.